# Procedure doesn't have compatible arguments

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Getting an error while invoking my procedure named `LOG_MSG_TEST()`. Procedure Schema name is `ADMINIST`.

My procedure has one `INTEGER` input parameter and one `VARCHAR` output parameter.

I am calling this procedure in the CLP using mentioned syntax:

```
call ADMINIST.LOG_MSG_TEST(1);
```

It is existing in the `SYSCAT.PROCEDURES` table, but I am still getting the following error:

> No authorized routine named "ADMINIST.LOG_MSG_TEST" of type
>   "PROCEDURE" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440,
>   SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.17.30

Comment: Include the procedure definition or at least its signature. How do you determine if it exists in `SYSCAT.PROCEDURES`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that your procedure has two parameters: an input INTEGER and an output VARCHAR, however, you call a procedure with only one argument, therefore DB2 is looking for the procedure that has only one INTEGER argument.

You should call it like so:

```
call ADMINIST.LOG_MSG_TEST(1,?);
```

where the question mark is a placeholder for the output argument.